# Can you aggregate feeds using a timespan greater than 24 hours?

Tags: getstream-io

The default format for aggregated feeds is the following:

```
{{ verb.id }}_{{ time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}
```

This returns activities grouped together within the last 24 hours.

Is it possible to group activities over a longer period of time, for example, 1 week?

Comment: `{{ verb.id }}_{{ time.strftime("%Y-%W") }}` groups by verb and week number

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to return activities for a longer period of time than 24 hours.

There is a max search depth for aggregated feeds, but it is based on activity volume - not timespan. Lots of activities will limit the timespan.